# Could not do OpenConsole.exe with Process in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to automate my ESP_IDF project using C# console application to run the commands such as "`idf.py -p COM5 build flash monitor`" (just an example). But when I start my C# application with a new process, I open `cmd.exe` and execute the command, but it fails giving no output. While I have tried setting the IDF path in the path variables (assuming that  might be the issue)and executing it separately again, it still doesn't work. What works is, me launching the ESP-IDF shell and running the command manually. I understand there might be some shell problem and further diagnosed in the TaskManager processes. In side the Terminal Process, the child process responsible for ESP-IDF was `OpenConsole.exe` while I tried to execute in cmd.exe (from the C# application). When I manually checked them, it seems like they work in different ways where OpenConsole.exe works probably using the linux kernel while cmd.exe using windows (my assumption). So, I tried to launch OpenConsole.exe from C# and it does not work. I have seen online that it is replaced by the name `conhost.exe`. But when I do run conhost.exe, the C# console application works by opening the new process but it turns out it is still cmd.exe. How can I run/open OpenConsole.exe to make use of my ESP-IDF commands?

Here is the code snipped I have used to in my C# Console App.

```
Process ExeCmd = new Process();
ExeCmd.StartInfo.FileName = "conhost.exe";
ExeCmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ExeCmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; 
ExeCmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
ExeCmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ExeCmd.Start();
ExeCmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("idf.py -p COM5 monitor");
ExeCmd.StandardInput.Flush();
ExeCmd.StandardInput.Close();
ExeCmd.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(ExeCmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Another behaviour is that, if it runs, it just opens idf.py python script in vscode although I could not understand why.

Comment: Have you tried doing this manually? Did it work? Try opening conhost.exe and entering the command you're trying to run.

Comment: Yes, manually it does works fine. One improvement done is that, a powershell script was written and through that i was able to execute but using the above method, no! I still could not understand why.